# Replace string in list with string from another list if it includes that string (in Python)

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have 2 lists:

`list1` is a list of language tags I want, it's only 2 for now: `list1 = ['en', 'es']`

`list2` is a list of audio IDs, and it can be of any length, for example `list2 = ['audio_es-419_1=384000', 'audio_en-US_5=256000', 'audio_en-US_4=384000', 'audio_es-419=128000']`

and so on

what I need is to look up strings from `list1` in `list2`, and if `list2` string includes string from `list1`, replace it with that string.

So for the above example of `list2` the desired output would be `['es', 'en', 'en', 'es']`

I do not mind that there are duplicate entries.

Have been struck on this for some time now, tried a few variations of for loops, with string replacement inside them, but unfortunately haven't been able to achieve what I need with my rather limited knowledge.

Would appreciate help with this one, and thanks in advance!

Comment: "Have been struck on this for some time now, tried a few variations of for loops, with string replacement inside them, but unfortunately haven't been able to achieve what I need with my rather limited knowledge." We can only tell you what was wrong with those attempts if you show them to us, and show us any [complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) that resulted. Please also read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't overwrite `list2`, but add a new List for this purpose.  I added a "bad" value for testing purposes

```
list1 = ['en', 'es']

list2 = ['audio_es-419_1=384000', 'audio_en-US_5=256000', 'audio_en-US_4=384000', 'audio_es-419=128000', 'blah']

list3 = []

for i in list2:
    for x in list1:
        if x in i:
            list3.append(x)

print(list3)

['es', 'en', 'en', 'es']
```

Comment: Good answer to the specific question. However I would suggest `if x in i` could result in problems in the future, and a regular expression match (or similar) would make for a better comparison.

Comment: @dkamins You are probably right, for more complicated strings regex would be more full proof